# Number of ways to pull balls

Tags: combinatorics

I have a box that contains  9 balls indistinguishable by touching:
$3$ balls are white,  $2$   balls are black, and $4$ are red.

I do this operation 4 times: I randomly pick a  ball, i note its color and i put it back.
Question: How many ways are there to get in the end 2 red balls and 2 white?

Comment: Do you mean how many different orders you can pull two red and two white?

Comment: yes. how many ordered lists (W,W,R,R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are six different orders you can pull two red balls and two white.

RWWR, 
RWRW, 
RRWW, 
WRRW, 
WRWR, 
WWRR

This can be found using:
$$\ _4P_2 / 2! = 6 $$
This works because the problem is essentially asking how many ways can you order 2 red balls with the rest being white.  We can find all the orders using $_4P_2$, but this will include some repeats because of two different red balls exchanging positions, so to remove these we divide be $2!$

Comment: Thanks for your help.